# Anime where girl turns into crystal/stone/glass and dies?

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

please forgive me, for this is going to be very vague.

I remember seeing a scene from an anime or cartoon in my childhood where this girl was surrounded by a group of people and it seemed like she was in a lot of pain, I don’t remember all the details but what I do remember is that she quickly turned into stone and sheds one last tear. I don’t remember if she screaming or anything… In fact, my memory could be skewed and this probably wasn’t even an anime or cartoon but does anybody have any type of clue of what I’m talking about?
I can’t seem to find this scene anywhere no matter how I search it.

if I see a video of it, I’ll probably recognize it right away.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding naomi. Could you offer any more details about the girl(how she looks, etc.)? Also, it would help to know how exactly she was encapsulated in the crystal(frozen in ice caveman style, or her body turned to stone).

Comment: ^_^ Or, rather, the Science Fiction and Fantasy SE.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Comment: Well, i don’t rlly remember how she looks, but it was her body/skin itself turning into stone. not smth frowing around or surrounding her

Comment: The answer might be found at https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCc0Ms_x8JmUF2E2jUIHAszw/videos, but I'm a bit scared to poke around too deeply. :-D

Comment: Probably not https://youtu.be/DeMCBtCHmKY?t=383

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TakenForGranite might also be useful.

Comment: *Fafner in the Azure* has "assimilated" pilots turning into crystal, but I couldn't say if there's a specific scene where one is surrounded by other people. Does [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zyx1.png) ring a bell? (Too thin to post as an answer, but o course if anyone else digs deeper and finds a match in the anime, post it as an answer!)

Comment: I remember this and I’ve been trying to find out what it’s from for years and correct me if I’m wrong on this but didn’t someone in the room cut their hand and pour blood on her?

Answer (score 5):

Is it this clip from the last episode of *[Haibane Renmei](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haibane_Renmei)*?

[image: Image from the last episode of Haibane Renmai]

> Rakka discovers that Reki's entire studio is painted like her cocoon dream. Rakka gives Reki the wooden tablet containing her true name, which fills the latter with despair. She has regretted ever being born in this world seven years ago, exiling herself from others and showing no trust in them. She wanted to always be there for Rakka in order to finally find salvation for herself. **She throws Rakka out of her studio, confronts a crumbling stone manifestation of herself, and relives her dream**. Rakka finds out the truth about the struggle Reki is going through via her diary, realizing that Reki wanted to protect her all along. Rakka goes back inside the studio, but is stopped by the manifestation. After Reki calls out for Rakka, the manifestation disappears. She saves Reki from being hit by a foggy image of a train. Reki departs on her Day of Flight, something all the Haibane will never forget. As spring nears, Rakka sees two cocoons beginning to sprout out of the ground inside a room.

GIF from [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/20206/where-is-this-gif-of-a-girl-turning-into-stone-and-breaking-apart-from/20208) on the Anime Stack Exchange, found with a search for `anime girl turned to stone`

I found the [clip in question](https://youtu.be/vaESjECeNrM?t=751), and it's looking like less of a match, but provided as a potential partial match.

Answer (score 3):

[*Crystal Blaze* (AKA *Glass Maiden*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glass_Maiden)) from 2008 has a girl turn to glass in the first episode and die.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Sounds promising so far, can you confirm that there's a last tear before she finishes turning?  An image or clip would also help, if you can find one.

Comment: Note: https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=bgUh68pt50g

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found your match; during the first season finale of [*Attack on Titan*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attack_on_Titan_(TV_series)), this girl Annie crystalizes in a clear diamond shape and has tears on her face. Many people are around her. Maybe it's *AoT*?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  No problem with a late answer; we're always looking for answers to unanswered questions no matter how old they are.  Do you think you could find an image of this to add to your answer?  It would make it much stronger.

Comment: One tiny problem... Annie doesn't die. Nor does she turn *into* crystal, but is merely surrounded by it